# Error specified dsn contains architecture mismatch between driver and application

Tags: php, sql-server

I have windows server 2012 machine (64-bit)with IIS installed in it.
I want to create a connection with sql server2012 (64-bit) through php code.
I created a dsn and when i run php file then i am getting an error

specified dsn contains architecture mismatch between driver and application

I tried
http://forum.gpsgate.com/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=13711 link.

I have also created dsn through 32-bit and 64 bit but error still remains same.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Run the ODBC configuration from `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe` instead and add your connection there as you most ran the default one in the control panel.

Comment: Whats the difference between runing default and from C:\
When i created connection from  C:\Windows\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe
then i am getting error Connection failed fro user
Also it is creating 32-bit connection.

Comment: Life saver - Silly me using the decoy ODBC manager that is prominently displayed in the control panel instead of the real one.  SMH

Answer (score 0):

After 1 hour of surfing i got the solution of my error

here is the solution

There are 2 versions of ODBC to worry about on 64-bit machines: the 32-bit version and the 64-bit version. So you have to Add or Change in 2 places to cover both types. Start - Admin Tools - Data Sources gets you to the 64-bit version; Start - Run -
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe gets you to the 32-bit version. Do all your adds/deletes/changes in both.  Installing the 32-bit drivers onto the 64-bit server and specifying that driver in the DSN should correct the problem. If you still encounter the error after adding or changing to the 32-bit driver(s), please contact support.

From the link http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21557767

This will help others to save their time.